# How to remove directory named 'Module - Copy20102018' with spaces from GIT repository

Tags: bash, git, shell

Wanted to remove the following directory from git repository.

**Module - Copy20102018**

I have removed one directory named '`Module - Copy20102018`' directly.

This folder was there in the git repository.

Now in `git status` this directory shows under header '**changes are not staged for commit**'.

```
deleted:    app/code/Module - Copy20102018/system.xml
deleted:    app/code/Module - Copy20102018/etc.xml
deleted:    app/code/Module - Copy20102018/123.php
deleted:    app/code/Module - Copy20102018/Report/JS/script.js
deleted:    app/code/Module - Copy20102018/Report/CSS/style.css
```

When I tried to run any of the following commands.

1. `git add app/code/Module - Copy20102018`

Gives message: `fatal: pathspec '-' did not match any files`

2. `git rm app/code/Module - Copy20102018`

Gives message: `fatal: not removing 'Module' recursively without -r`

3. `git checkout app/code/Module - Copy20102018`

Gives message :

```
error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'Copy20102018' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any other way to remove this kind of folder from `git` repository.

Comment: Your command line interpreter sees "hello world" as two separate items, "hello" followed by "world". So if you run `git add hello world`, you're telling Git: add `hello`, and add `world`. How do you get your command interpreter to *not* see these as two separate items? Exercise for the student: does it depend in the command interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this would be a duplicate, but I cannot seem to find one - bash interprets by defaults spaces as word breaks so

```
git rm /a/b - c
```

is interpreted the same as if you ran

```
git rm /a/b
git rm -
git rm c
```

You need to quote filenames that contain spaces:

```
git rm '/a/b - c'
```

or escape the spaces. If this is a folder you need the recursive flag `-r`.

Comment: using quotes working successfully.  `git add 'app/code/Module - Copy20102018'` answer is accepted.